# Split window with shortcut key

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut to split editor window in eclipse? Or can I set this?

Comment: Note: starting with Eclipse Luna 4.4 M4, those shortcut will be  `Ctrl+_` for **split horizontally**, and `Ctrl+{` for **split vertically**: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20567058/6309)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a window/view in Eclipse IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471578/how-do-you-split-a-window-view-in-eclipse-ide)

Comment: @AndyThomas Hey, my question had been made earlier.

Comment: @Sangdol - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those shortcuts will exist soon (4.4 M4+), as announced by Lars Vogel (December 2013) in "[Split editor implemented in Eclipse Luna 4.4 M4 Luna](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/12/12/split-editor-implemented-in-eclipse-m4-luna-solves-bug-8009-one-of-the-highest-voted-bug-in-eclipse-platform/)":

**(4.4 M4+) shortcut for splitting is**:

> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> for **split horizontally**, and
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> for **split vertically**.

**4.4 final** (update October 2014)

[Szorstki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030134/szorstki) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641430/split-window-with-shortcut-key/20567058?noredirect=1#comment41143421_20567058):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>

> Worked in my Eclipse Luna

---

[image: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=238285]

### Split editor implemented in Eclipse M4 Luna 4.4 ([Bug 8009](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8009))

> The split editor functionality has been developed in [Bug 378298](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378298), and will be available as of Eclipse Luna M4. The Note & Newsworthy of Eclipse Luna M4 will contain the announcement.

---

As commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641430/split-window-with-shortcut-key/20567058?noredirect=1#comment55675815_20567058) by [Tobias Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1498151/tobias-lott), there is still a [pending bug (438562)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438562) regarding keyboard layouts, e.g. German, Swiss German or Italian.

Comment: Wonder when they run out of shortcut key combinations. I somewhat miss WordStar...

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+_ and
Ctrl+Shift+{
Worked in my Eclipse Luna

Comment: @Szorstki Thank you. I have included those shortcuts in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Unfortunately the vertical split doesn't work with some keyboard layouts, e.g. German, Swiss German or Italian. See [Bug 438562](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438562)

Comment: @TobiasLott Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

[Nope](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8009) this is one of the oldest outstanding enhancement requests in Eclipse. As noted in the last comment, it will be 10 years old next month.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse doesn’t support this. However, you can do this by installing the [Emacs+ plugin](http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/).

Once you’ve installed the plugin, you can just press Ctrl-X, then 2 or 3 depending on whether you want to split it horizontally or vertically respectively.

You need to first either configure your key binding to the Emacs+ Scheme (see Emacs+ installation instructions) or configure the keys manually using the command keys described on the Emacs+ homepage to configure the keys.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Split Editor Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/split-editor-plug/metrics). When you install this plugin, you can assign shortcut key to split editor.

Comment: on install repositry seems to be missing, installed handysplit instead

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> in Indigo.

Comment: That is playing on semantics really. Effectively there is no difference

Comment: No, it's a big difference. In emacs for example, you do control-x-2 to spit a window. In Eclipse you have to drag the editor window to make it a half window and then create a new editor. If you just do a new editor without doing that, then it creates the editor in a different tab, but it's not a split window.

Comment: No, a new editor (side by side) on Eclipse achieves the same without additional need to drag, so I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: @FrancisUpton maybe a picture would help prussswan.