# How do you split and unsplit a window/view in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide

How do you split a window/view in Eclipse IDE? I want to edit code while viewing the different code in the same file.

If there is a trick to open the same file twice, this might do, but I would rather just split the one current view instead of having two of the same which might get confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse - Same .Java file in split view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198822/eclipse-same-java-file-in-split-view)

Comment: That earlier question could be closed as the duplicate. This question has better, more contemporary answers.

Comment: If split happened by mistake, to unsplit press "ctrl"+"shift"+"-". This feature annoys me a lot.

Comment: window>editor>Toggle split editor will get rid of the unexpected split, @Rauli shortcut didn't work for me.

Comment: On Mac OS, the corresponding key combination to unsplit is ⌘ ⇧ - ("cmd"+"shift"+"-"). But this is only for horizontal splits. See my answer below for both horizontal split and vertical split.

Answer (score 366, accepted):

This is possible with the menu items **Window>Editor>Toggle Split Editor**.

Current shortcut for splitting is:

[Azerty keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#French):

> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> for **split horizontally**, and
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> for **split vertically**.

[Qwerty US keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#United_States):

> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (accessing <kbd>_</kbd>) for **split horizontally**, and
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> (accessing <kbd>{</kbd>) for **split vertically**.

**MacOS - Qwerty US keyboard:**

> - <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (accessing <kbd>_</kbd>) for **split horizontally**, and
> - <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> (accessing <kbd>{</kbd>) for **split vertically**.

On any other keyboard if a required key is unavailable (like <kbd>{</kbd> on a german Qwertz keyboard), the following generic approach may work:

> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + ASCII code + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then release <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Example: ASCII for '{' = 123, so press 'Alt', '1', '2', '3', 'Ctrl' and release 'Alt', effectively typing '{' while 'Ctrl' is pressed, to **split vertically**.

Example of vertical split:

[image: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=238285]

PS:

- The menu items **Window>Editor>Toggle Split Editor** were added with Eclipse Luna 4.4 M4, as mentioned by Lars Vogel in "[Split editor implemented in Eclipse M4 Luna](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/12/12/split-editor-implemented-in-eclipse-m4-luna-solves-bug-8009-one-of-the-highest-voted-bug-in-eclipse-platform/)"
- The split editor is one of the oldest and most upvoted Eclipse bug! [Bug 8009](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8009)
- The split editor functionality has been developed in [Bug 378298](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378298), and will be available as of Eclipse Luna M4. The Note & Newsworthy of Eclipse Luna M4 will contain the announcement.

Comment: I have to give this as the new accepted answer then. Let me know if anyone has any issues with it, as I cannot test this myself. Thank you for the update!

Comment: Anyone know if this works on a Mac? I've had no success. And surely there's something about this feature in the menus?

Comment: @TimothyDean did you getthe very latest 4.4Mx on your Mac?

Comment: @TimothyDean note: those shortcuts might have changed since Dec. 2013: see comment 44 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378298#c44.

Comment: I read through those already. Nothing worked. On the other hand, I may have been a little too quick to ask -- I'm using the Spring Tool Suite, not vanilla Eclipse -- that might change some things too.

Comment: When using RDP I am able to split vertically with Ctrl+{ but eclipse does not recognize Ctrl+_  .  However, if I rebind the action to Ctrl+Shift+- it works.

Comment: @VonC Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

Comment: Be sure to press Ctrl-Shift-'-', not Ctrl-'-'. That's what Ctrl-_ requires.

Comment: @Arkadiy True: I have edited the answer to differentiate the keyboards.

Comment: +1 for the Azerty & Qwerty keyboard solution.  It is surprising to see that official documentation lacks such an important information.

Comment: Using Luna 4.4 JEE version with an Azerty keyboard, `Ctrl+_` works but not `Ctrl+{`

Comment: @JacquesLeRoux that seems consistent with where the '`{`' is placed in an azerty keyboard.

Comment: It worked for me ...  by accident.  I had to come here to learn how to turn if  it off (and avoid making the same typing mistake in the future)

Comment: Thanks, this is a life saver and I end up googling it any time I split my window by mistake. I think that for an IDE, using `{` as part of a keyboard shortcut is not the brightest idea one can have.

Answer (score 99):

You can open a **new editor** from the Window menu.

This will give you your current editor once again.

Comment: Thank you. So open a new editor and adjust the two as I please. Is this the only way? A split function would be best if it existed.

Comment: You can click and hold on the editors title and drag it to the lower side of your screen. It will snap there and Eclipse will present you something very similar to a split screen. (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHdvDwjQELI)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Eclipse Kepler any more. The option still lives on the Window menu, but seems to do nothing. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've just figured it out - it no longer automatically splits the screen and instead required that you click the tab and drag to another part of the window.

Comment: Be very careful in Kepler: each instance of the file window is *independant*. If you modify the content in one, the other is *not* modified. It really is editing the same file in two different editors with all the issues of concurrent editing. It would still work somewhat if you use one instance as a read-only reference.

Comment: so i opened a new splitted window. But now I want to close that window. but how to do it. there is only minimize and maximize buttons. 9No close button). eventhough the file is closed that window exists!!!

Answer (score 36):

If you right click on one of the tabs, one of the options should be **New Editor** (for me, it's at the bottom). Select that, and then drag the new tab onto the bottom scroll bar of the code editor, which will split the editor panel in two.

Comment: The key is to drag the new opened editor to reach the bottom border of the old editor, then a black arrow and a black line at the middle of the old editor will appear to indicate that you split the editor successfully.

Answer (score 35):

**Just click and drag editor title to left, right, top or bottom**

Comment: Ah ha! Just drag it back. However...this is weird. Sometimes when I drag a *single* tab down it moves all tabs *except* one down, instead of just the one I drug down. Other times it moves just the one I drug down. I can't figure that one out. Maybe it is an order of operations/order of tabs opened thing? Or maybe it is a bug?

Comment: @GabrielStaples just drag that split window in between other screens tab where you want to position

Answer (score 22):

I tried the above solutions in Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 but couldn't open two (or multiple editor windows for different files side by side).

**Simplest Solution:**

1. Open all files you want in a single window.
2. Drag the **tab** of each of the files to right or to the left, eclipse will automatically display a split screen display and will split the editor into two windows once you leave the mouse button.
3. repeat for each file/tab.

Happy Coding!

Comment: This is the best answer. The others either open a duplicate tab only or have way too many steps.

Comment: This is the only legit answer that tells how to view 2 differeent files side by side. The most voted answer shows how to split the same file (which doesn't answer the question)

Answer (score 20):

Side by side editors in single Eclipse window.

1. You have an Eclipse window showing a single editor.
2. Window -> new editor.  You now have two editor tabs.
3. Click and drag one tab towards the right and a green outline of a vertical screen appears (drag tag towards the bottom and an outline of a horizontal screen outline appears). You can let go as soon as the outline appears.
4. Open file of choice in 2nd editor (recent files show up at bottom of file menu).

ADT/Eclipse:Build: v22.3.0-887826

Comment: This is a very nice feature and good to know, but technically the question was about splitting the view for observing two parts within the same file. Your answer applies to viewing separate files side-by-side.

Comment: The way Stephen described it, you'll get two editors on the same file.

Comment: Although I like the Eclipse Luna answer in theory, this is the answer I chose because I am on an older version. Despite akauppi's comment of 3/20/14, I had no problem following the instructions and having the same file on the left and right.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to check an eclipse plugin called [HandySplit](https://github.com/akikhtenko/HandySplit)

It allows to split an editor into two and move tabs from one editors stack to another with **keyboard shortcuts only**.

That works on Eclipse Juno or higher.
For the previous Eclipse versions check [this](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/one-click-editor-splitting-in-eclipse.html) out

Comment: awesome plugin. can navigate/split/clone/move/exchange views just from keyboard. perfect!

Answer (score 6):

Simply go to Window > New Window

This will open up a new window of the same Workspace in eclipse.

You can open up separate files in each Window.

Comment: You can NOT  open several windows of the same Workspace, in eclipse.

Comment: Indeed, you can. At least in current versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Below are the steps to `split` editor horizontally or vertically
go to:

```
Window -> Editor -> Toggle Split Editor (Horizontal)
```

to split editor horizontally or

```
Window -> Editor -> Toggle Split Editor (vertical)
```

to split editor vertically.

It will open two editors side by side or will pileup tow.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see two different files in same eclipse you can,

> Right-click a tab -> **Detach**

Now you can see both files at the same time without opening new eclipse and you can **drag and reatach** to tabs again.

Comment: Useful for simultaneous view/comparison of two different files...

Comment: I don't have a detach option using eclipse  2023-3.  Has it been removed?  Or, perhaps, relocated?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, the key combination to toggle spit/unsplit for horizontal split is ⌘ ⇧ - ("cmd"+"shift"+"-"), whereas for vertical split, it is ⌘ ⇧ [ ("cmd"+"shift"+"[")