# Binding 2 editors'scrollbars

Tags: eclipse, ide

When editing code in Eclipse, you can have multiple editors opened, each represented by a tab.
You can also have 2 (or more) editors displayed at the same time.
This can be done like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9471578/544896).

Then, there is another option that comes handy : *Show Source of Selected Element Only*.
(I believe it is not enabled per default so you have to right click on the toolbar, choose *Customize Perspective...* and in the *Toolbar visibility* tab, you have to enable *Editor Presentation* and its children)

This only displays the method in which the cursor is, for each editor.
I use this feature to compare functions to know if I can refactor code that looks too similar.

But sadly I have not found an option to bind the 2 scroll bars like in the *Compare Editor*.
So when I scroll in one editor, the other one is scrolled proportionally.

Is this a hidden feature ? Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this ?

Thank you !