# How do you join back the split editor panes in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

On Eclipse, with Window -> New Editor or by drag/drop method* I could have one more editor panes in my eclipse work area. Now how do I remove that extra pane when I do not need it anymore. All it allows me now is to minimize/maximize that editor extra pane. It just sticks around. Shouldn't there be a collapse or close extra editor panes (that is without me requiring to do Window->Reset Perspective!)

- Ref: answers to another question: [How do you split and unsplit a window/view in Eclipse IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471578/how-do-you-split-a-window-view-in-eclipse-ide)

Comment: Just closing the editor in the pane works for me on Eclipse 4.3

Comment: Or drag the open editor(s) to the other editor area; the empty one will disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HandySplit](https://github.com/akikhtenko/HandySplit) has a flatten action that you need and other capabilities that you might find useful.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on a tab in the window you want to close and select "close all".  This will close the split window (and close any tabs in that window that have not been dragged to another window).